# How to Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with SP2 from a command line.

Everything works fine, but the Configuration Manager is not being installed.

The file I'm using is `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe`

the command line is

```
sqlexprwt_x64_ENU /q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL 
      /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 
      /sqlsvcaccount=NT Authority\System /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin 
      /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms 
      /securitymode=SQL /sapwd=XXXXXXX /tcpenabled=1 
      /sqlsvcstartuptype=Automatic /browsersvcstartuptype=Automatic
```

I've also tried `/features=SQL,TOOLS` without success.

A manual install installs Config Manager and SSMS etc etc. so it can be done; but not from a command line apparently.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT to expand on dvdd's answer: the SSMS parameter to Features was the missing ingredient. Given its name, I had assumed (yes, I know) that it installed SSMS; but in fact it has the effect of installing Config Manager even when not installing using the 'wt' version of the exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My production deployments include the install parameter `/features=SQLENGINE,SSMS` to accomplish this task.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying this installs Configuration Manager, not just SSMS?

Comment: Yes sir. After including this parameter, I have the following available in the start menu: SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Server Configuration Manager.

I should clarify that my installation command is `"full\path\sqlexprwt_x64_enu.exe" /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /CONFIGURATIONFILE=FULL\PATH\AnswerFile.ini`. 
AnswerFile.ini contains the line `/features=SQLENGINE,SSMS`. I run this command on Windows Server 2008 R2 machines. Check here for more information on answer file contents: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.105).aspx).